# How can I find duplicate lines in a text file and print them?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file with some 1,200 rows. Some of them are duplicates.

How could I find the duplicate lines in the file (but not worrying about case) and then print out the line's text on the screen, so I can go off and find it? I don't want to delete them or anything, just find which lines they might be.

Comment: Do you know how to (1) get lines from the file (2) compare strings? If yes to both, then you are only left with the problem of an efficient comparison scheme. So, on what part of the problem are you stuck?

Comment: @dmckee Yes to two, but not excluding case. No to one.

Comment: I'm very sorry to all here :(

Comment: The point of the comment isn't to make you feel bad, but to help you write better questions. Here you really have two questions: (1) how to perform a case insensitive comparison of strings and (2) how to efficiently store the lines already seen and compare against them. The first is probably answered on Stack Overflow already, so you cold search for that. The second would have been a much more explicit questions. IN any case, I see that you have gotten good answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is pretty easy with a set:

```
with open('file') as f:
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        if line_lower in seen:
            print(line)
        else:
            seen.add(line_lower)
```

Comment: @unwind -- sorry for rolling back your edit.  I noticed an indentation error in my code that you apparently missed too and for some reason I thought you added it :p ... Anyway, all is well now and I've incorporated your changes.

Comment: I didn't try this code snipped but wouldn't you have to do something like f.read() or f.readlines() instead of only f?

Comment: @tehmisvh -- Nope.  `file` objects are iterators.  You can iterate over them directly.  :)  -- That's a really cool design decision if you ask me.

Comment: Works perfectly. There are huge gaps in the print out between the lines, almost like it prints the black lines too, but it does work anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if a line appears three times it will print twice in the results.  It's probably a non-issue.

Comment: The huge gaps are blank lines.  Since blank lines appear more than once they're getting printed.  To suppress that change the if statement to `if line_lower in seen and line_lower.strip():`.  Or add as first line of the for-statement `if not line.strip(): continue`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That got rid of the blank lines, thank you.

Comment: @samiles -- The huge gaps are probably because your datafile has blank lines (which are repeated, and therefore printed each time you see it).

Answer (score 9):

as there are only 1200 lines, so you can also use `collections.Counter()`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> with open('data1.txt') as f:
...     c=Counter(c.strip().lower() for c in f if c.strip()) #for case-insensitive search
...     for line in c:
...         if c[line]>1:
...             print line
...
```

if `data1.txt` is something like this:

```
ABC
abc
aBc
CAB
caB
bca
BcA
acb
```

**output is:**

```
cab
abc
bca
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Finding Case-Insensitive Duplicates

This won't give you line numbers, but it *will* give you a list of duplicate lines which you can then investigate further. For example:

```
tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' < /tmp/foo | sort | uniq -d
```

#### Example Data File

```
# /tmp/foo
one
One
oNe
two
three
```

The pipeline listed above will correctly yield:

> one

#### Finding the Line Numbers

You could then grep for related line numbers like so:

```
grep --ignore-case --line-number one /tmp/foo
```