# How to detect the duplicate sentence from a list that full of sentence?

Tags: python

I've tried this before:

```
path = input()
f = open(path,'r+', encoding='utf-8')
data = f.readlines()
list1 = []
list1 = [data]
list2 = []
list2 = [x for n, x in enumerate(list1) if x in list1[:n]]
print(list2)
```

Output : [] (nothing else)
I can sure my txt file have 3 lines of duplicated sentence by observation but why the program can't detect it?
or any better code on detecting duplicated sentence rather than using enumerate function?

```
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [Kircher Alden]- Alas, alas, that great COVER
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [Kircher Alden]- Alas, alas, that great COVER
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [Oseph Steven]- 
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [Kircher Alden]- Alas, alas, that great COVER
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [sheep Lec]- こんぬい～！
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [なおるひ]- こんぬい～
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [ken.]- こんぬい～
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [迦楼羅]- 自称w
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [Nikki_watamate]- こんぬい～～
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [またじろうmatajirou]- こんばんはー！！
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [いちにー]- ん？
2021-07-17 19:03:05 [桜小路こいし]- こんぬい～
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [錯乱した青年C]- こんぬいー
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [博雅]- こんぬい～
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [Ramon Gullett]- 直 到 永 永 远 远 。
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [Ramon Gullett]- 直 到 永 永 远 远 。
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [Ramon Gullett]- 直 到 永 永 远 远 。
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [出雲]- こんぬい～！
2021-07-17 19:03:06 [。ロクマル]- こんぬい〜！
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [ルシルイ「RushiRui」]- こんぬい〜
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [たけゆき]- こんぬい～
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [sss]- かな？
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [ももてぃん]- こんぬい！！！
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [Calico cat]- 
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [Rari Ehlani]- как будто судьи в суде
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [ちゃかげ]- ん？
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [dew 0w0]- Hi friend
2021-07-17 19:03:07 [メネスexam]- かな？
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [kotoharu]- なんでも？！
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [夏目陽射]- おおー！！
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Jackson Winget]- 哀 哉 ， 哀 哉 ， 这 大 COVER 阿
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Dong Vaught]- 直 到 永 永 远 远 。
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [オウィスクリーク]- 草
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [ストラ]- 自称ｗ
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [カルマ]- 
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Jackson Winget]- 哀 哉 ， 哀 哉 ， 这 大 COVER 阿
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Jackson Winget]- 哀 哉 ， 哀 哉 ， 这 大 COVER 阿
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [トール]- 草
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Gordon Fryer]- Alas, alas, that great COVER
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Dong Vaught]- 直 到 永 永 远 远 。
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Dong Vaught]- 直 到 永 永 远 远 。
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [グリード]- 草
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Gordon Fryer]- Alas, alas, that great COVER
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [とどぐら雄]- ふーたん！今日はよろしくね
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [miro]- lol
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [Gordon Fryer]- Alas, alas, that great COVER
2021-07-17 19:03:08 [大分県のボードゲーマー]- 自称ｗ
2021-07-17 19:03:09 [オッドポール三等軍曹]- かな？草
2021-07-17 19:03:09 [renrenドドド]- 
2021-07-17 19:03:09 [ばとうさ]- こんぬい～
2021-07-17 19:03:09 [プレーネ]- 草
```

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: OK
its actually the youtube chatroom data, using pytchat to record.
such as :
2021-08-04 20:53:08 I have a mouse !
2021-08-04 20:53:08 I have a mouse !
2021-08-04 20:53:08 I have a mouse !
2021-08-04 20:53:09 I dont have a mouse !
......

Comment: Why do you put the list `data` in another list?

Comment: @Ken Please place your sample data into the original question rather than in a comment.

Comment: @DaveL17, Sure, i will edit the post

Comment: I edited the post, and this is just a part of the original data, the remaining is the same format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find duplicate lines in a text file and print them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937798/how-can-i-find-duplicate-lines-in-a-text-file-and-print-them)

Comment: Yes, i have solved the problem, Thx for everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not be looking up a list of things in a list: List lookups are slow and you will get very bad performance as the list length goes up (google "quadratic behavior").

If your sentences are really identical, character for character, this would be an efficient way to find out:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(path,'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    sentences = Counter(f)  # read line by line and count

duplicates = [s for s in sentences if sentences[s] > 1]
```

If the lines are not completely identical, you'll need to read them in and clean up first, sort of like this:

```
with open(path,'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    raw = list(f)
    # clean the strings here, then 

    sentences = Counter(raw)  # read line by line and count
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to detect if there are duplicate sentences in a file, use set()

```
if len(list(f.readlines()))==len(set(f.readlines())):
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list of lines, so `list1` is a list of one item: a list of lines.  If instead you did `list1 = data`, your duplicates should be found.

Comment: Thx i will try it now !